# How to get type of inherited generic

Tags: c#, reflection

I have these classes:

```
public abstract class BaseClass{}
public class CustomerService : BaseClass<Customer>{}
public class ProductService : BaseClass<Product>{}
public class UserService : BaseClass<User>{}
```

at run time I have this type: `entity.GetType()` which will return the generic type: `Customer` for example.

How can I get the type of `CustomerService` if I have `Customer` type at runtime?
They are all in the same namespace.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just looking for a class whose direct base type is the relevant `BaseClass<T>`, you can use code like this:

```
var targetBaseType = typeof(BaseClass<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
var type = typeof(BaseClass<>).Assembly.GetTypes()
                              .Single(t => t.BaseType == targetBaseType);
```

To avoid a linear search each time, you might want to create a `Dictionary<Type, Type>` where the key is the entity type, and the value is the service type. You could either set that up with reflection, or just create it manually. Then it's *really* simple:

```
var type = serviceTypeDictionary[entityType];
```

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry for not mentioning, but BaseClass is abstract, and I cannot create an instance out of it.

Comment: Thank you, my bad! I think I mistakenly down voated you, can you please edit your answer so I can fix it?

Comment: Done, sorry for that, nobody can down vote Jon Skeet. nobody!